# Open-source Java/JVM back-of-the-book index generation library

Tags: java, automation, plain-text, document-indexing

I'm currently working on some automation software for the creation of non-fiction books (actual, printed books). As part of this, I need to be able to create a reasonable-quality "back of the book" index in a fully automated fashion. The input for creating the index is the continuous text of the book plus additional page markers. There are no special markers for "important" or "index-worthy" words, so the software would have to figure out by itself which words (and bigrams) need to be included in the index, and which occurrence should be considered the "main" (typically bolded) occurrence (see illustrative example below).

I fully realize that this is no easy task, and really a project in itself (i.e., implementing this from scratch is out of the scope of my project). The trickiest part is probably how to select index-worthy words and bigrams without any sort of indexing hints in the text, and I figure that it might involve some kind of AI/ML language model. I'm aware of Lucene/Solr, but I need an actual printable index, not just some index data structure that can be queried.

I've looked in all the usual places (mvnrepository, Github, Google) but all I've come up with is commercial (and often costly) indexing software (PDF Index Generator, CIndex, TeXyz, etc.), which frequently is only available on Windows. Is book indexing really one of the last niches where no open-source solution exists? (I find that hard to believe, in a world, where there are open-source solutions for everything from speech recognition to eye tracking)

Can someone point me to an open-source library that can produce book indexes of reasonable quality? (preferably, Java or JVM-based, but at this point I'm happy to integrate with anything I can get)

[image]